# Transit visa Sydney international airport

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, syd

I am landing in Sydney at T1 from Fiji. 3 hours later I need to have collected luggage and checked in for my Sydney to UK flight, still at T1, just a different carrier. Does this mean I will have to go through customs and immigration? I’ve no idea.

Basically, I need to know if I need a transit visa. The immigration website states that if I'm in transit and don’t leave the transit lounge then it’s fine but... what’s the transit lounge? The terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Did you buy tickets separately? If yes, you need go through immigration and customs. If you bought them from one carrier, but you have a connecting flight with another carrier from the same airport, you do not need go through customs.

> Do I need a visa to transit through Australia?

You may need a Transit visa (subclass 771) if you plan to travel through Australia to another country.

If you are transiting though Australia for less than eight hours and you do not need to leave the airport transit lounge (except to board your connecting flight), you may not need to apply for a transit visa (subclass 771).

If you are going to stay in Australia for longer than 72 hours, you cannot get a transit visa, and you will need to apply for another type of visa.

If you belong to one of the categories and meet the criteria outlined below, you can transit through Australia without applying for a visa.

https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia

Comment: "if yes you need go thru customs" Generally yes, but sometimes the check-in agent will agree to through-check your bags, even on a non-through-ticket (they can't/won't always, though). In this case (or with hand-baggage only) you should be able to check in at the transit desk, which will be somewhere airside.